# asp custom format for string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, string

i need to apply a specific format to a string for a model, something like:

[DataType(DataType.Text), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{##-###-###-###-###-###-##-###}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]

Meaning this is not a credit card number is an id and is a string. so the question es how to apply any custom format to a string, prefered directly in model class and not a view or using js, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use regular expression

[a-z,0-9,A-Z]{2}[-][a-z,0-9,A-Z]{3}[-][a-z,0-9,A-Z]{3}[-][a-z,0-9,A-Z]{3}[-][a-z,0-9,A-Z]{3}[-][a-z,0-9,A-Z]{3}[-][a-z,0-9,A-Z]{2}[-][a-z,0-9,A-Z]{3}

- [a-z,0-9,A-Z]{2} match 2 character in range a-z,0-9,A-Z
- [-] match with - separator

Then, you can do something like that

```
[RegularExpression(@"[a-z,0-9,A-Z]{2}[-][a-z,0-9,A-Z]{3}[-][a-z,0-9,A-Z]{3}[-][a-z,0-9,A-Z]{3}[-][a-z,0-9,A-Z]{3}[-][a-z,0-9,A-Z]{3}[-][a-z,0-9,A-Z]{2}[-][a-z,0-9,A-Z]{3}")]
public string myVal{get;set;}
```

- !#-###-###-###-#$#-###-##-### not pass
- 12-123-abc-123-s23-122-32-cc2 pass
- aa-bbb-ccc-ddd-eee-fff-gg-hhh pass
- 12-345-678-910-111-213-14-156 pass
- 1a-2b3-c4d-5e6-f7g-hij-kl-123 pass
- 1a-2b3-c4d-5e6-f7g-hij-kl-1!3 not pass

If you accept any word in you digit, you can use

\w{2}[-]\w{3}[-]\w{3}[-]\w{3}[-]\w{3}[-]\w{3}[-]\w{2}[-]\w{3}

```
[RegularExpression(@"\w{2}[-]\w{3}[-]\w{3}[-]\w{3}[-]\w{3}[-]\w{3}[-]\w{2}[-]\w{3}")]
public string myVal{get;set;}
```

Comment: I have tried this, maybe i was assuming something that is not, i see no changes at all on representation of existent data, i have data like: 0420000101700910700000 already on a database, the data is good storaged, i don't want the saved data be: 04-200-0001-017-009-107-00-000; the data is saved correctly, but when i see the data on an input i wanna see the format string: 04-200-0001-017-009-107-00-000; also if i edit the data i do not  want to write - character i want it does automatically, is correct what i'm trying to do it in the model or it need to be on input event onchange with js ?

Comment: Then, you need a "real time" validation and backend validation.Where you take your input ? Console app, mvc app, web app?

Comment: try that :
string data = "12123abc123s2312232cc2";
data= Regex.Replace(data, @"(\w{2})(\w{3})(\w{3})(\w{3})(\w{3})(\w{3})(\w{2})(\w{3})", @"$1-$2-$3-$4-$5-$6-$7-$8");
  Console.Write(data);